# 400 bad request using wcf post and postman api

Tags: c#, json, wcf, iis, web-config

I keep getting stuck with this error on my postman api where I want to send a large string as one of the parameters to my web service when it is hosted on a local server. When I test the service on localhost it works fine.[Screenshot of postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Fgl.png)

The web service is supposed to return the path of an image that is saved in the server. [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47se0.png)
The above string worked because it is a much smaller string of around 4000 characters unlike the string I used before which is almost 14000 characters long.

Searching on the internet and I found that I need to make changes in my Web.config file specifically the maxJsonLength  maxRequestLength but this did not work for me.

Any suggestions?